# Ionic Runtime Error Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Tags: typescript, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database, ionic2

My code in home.ts is like this

```
schools: any;

 ionViewWillLoad(){

   this.afoDatabase.list('/students',
  {
    query:{
          orderByChild: 'department',
          equalTo: this.schools[0].department
        }
  }).subscribe(snap => {
    this.students = snap;
  });
  }
```

Actually the variable **schools** is not set to any value at the start. There is an option to set the **schools** variable only after the page load.
When I hardcode value for **equalTo** to "xyz" instead of this.schools[0].department it is working as expected.

So now how should I frame the query so that I will not get

> Runtime Error Cannot read property '0' of undefined

**Update:**

When I changed schools declaration to

```
schools: any[]=[];
```

I am getting following Error

> *Cannot read property 'department' of undefined*

Whenever the value is defined then only I want to have query, otherwise I don't want to have query. How can I write this condition?

Comment: it should be an array type as `schools: any[ ] = [ ];`

Comment: If declare that as array then I get Cannot read property 'department' of undefined

Comment: Where in code schools array getting populated? Is it before ionViewWillLoad()

Comment: No. User can set it only after the loading of the page.

Comment: @vjnan369 did you find a solution to your problem? I am facing a similar issue as well as described below.

Answer (score 0):

I am facing the same issue (I am learning ionic ). The only way I am able to solve it by putting the function call in both `ngOnInit` and `ionViewWillEnter`. When i declare the array then i get an error regarding "title" property.

When I remove the function call from `ngOnInit` i get the error: `ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined`.

My example is very simple. I have a service which has a private array with a getter to get its content. I am not making any database calls for my example.

And here is the type script code that works for me.

```
  loadedPlaces: Place[];
  listedLoadedPlaces: Place[]; //for virtual scroll

  constructor(private placesService: PlacesService, private menuCntrl: MenuController) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log('ngOnInIt');
    this.loadData();
  }

  ionViewWillEnter(){
    console.log('ionViewWillEnter');
    this.loadData();
  }

  loadData(){
    this.loadedPlaces = this.placesService.places; //getter property
    //for the virtual scroll
    this.listedLoadedPlaces = this.loadedPlaces.slice(1);
  }
```

My environment

```
node: v14.15.5
npm: 6.14.11
angular: 11.2.0
ionic: 6.13.1
```